# How do i fetch javascript errors of advertising in a proper way? (stacktrace)

Tags: javascript, logging, error-handling, trace, ads

We are running a website and currently tracking all appearing javascript errors by pushing them to a logging db like the following:

```
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
      var loggerUrl = logger,
          parameters = "?description=" + escape(errorMessage)
          + "&amp;url=" + escape(url)
          + "&amp;line=" + escape(line)
          + "&amp;parent_url=" + escape(document.location.href)
});
```

This works well for javascript errors caused by ourselves, but it seems impossible for us to get a better view on all (and im talking about 100k+ a day) errors which are caused by some ads which are written in a dirty way.

I tried tracekit.js and stacktrace.js but i could not manage to get it running properly in a way to deliver more information about the errors.

Ads are implemented in a normal way (1-3 redirects from adserver to adserver untill we finally get an ads displayed).

Comment: They are likely not running in the scope of your page but instead in (generated) iframes. You will not be able to catch those from your page

Comment: no chance to get any more detailed information about it?

Comment: Not unless you serve all the ads yourself via a proxy on your server

Comment: Why exactly do you want to trace errors in the code of your ads?

Comment: Broken ads are worth nothing in terms of money, thats why we try to help our advertiser to identify broken campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: I've sold Muscula years ago and it's a paid service]

If you are already logging the errors, but want more details on them, you could try [Muscula](http://muscula.com) it does automatic try catch insertion, that often gives real call stacks etc. for errors. (Not every time)

Disclosure: I'm the creator of Muscula.

Comment: Thanks! Ill give it a try next week, when im back at the office